# Opening a YUI Panel from an onclick event

Tags: javascript, dom-events, yui

I was wondering if it was possible to set and open a YUI panel using an onclick event like so:

```
<a href="#" onclick="myPanel = new YAHOO.widget.Panel("myPanel"); 
myPanel.setHeader('Header'); myPanel.setBody('Body'); 
myPanel.setFooter('Footer'); myPanel.render('document.body'); 
myPanel.show();"></a>
```

Answer (score 0):

To show a Panel from the click event of another element you need to: create the Panel, render it hidden (using `visible: false`) and then `show()` it from the click event handler. Here's an example:

```
var panel = new Y.Panel({
    bodyContent: 'foo',
    centered: true,
    width: 200,
    height: 100,
    visible: false //render the panel, but keep it hidden
});
panel.render();

// show the panel with a click
Y.one('#foo').on('click', function () {
    panel.show();
});
```